# Can an integer be splitted and encoded into alphabets?

Tags: c

There is an encoding scheme where integer 1 encodes character 'A', integer 2 encodes character 'B' and so on till integer 26 which encodes character 'Z'. With this encoding scheme,we should program to count all possible decodings of a given digit sequence

For example, if the digit sequence is "12" then there are two possible decodings for this - One of them is 'AB' when we decode 1 as 'A' and 2 as 'B'. Now we can also decode this digit sequence "12" as 'L' when we decode digits 1 and 2 taken together as an integer 12.

Similarly for digit sequence "1223" there are five possible decodings.
1, 2, 2, 3 - ABBC

1, 2, 23 - ABW

1, 22, 3 - AVC

12, 2, 3 - LBC

12, 23 - LW

For digit sequence "1234" there are three possible decodings.

1, 2, 3, 4 - ABCD

1, 23, 4 - AWD

12, 3, 4 - LBD

Note that because integer 34 does not have any valid decoding, we cannot decode "1234" as 1,2,34 or as 12,34 where digits 3 and 4 are decoded together(as an integer 34) to some character.
Few assumptions that we can make here

1. Number of possible decodings for an empty sequence is 0.
2. There would be no 0's at the very beginning of digit sequence. That means, no digit sequence would start from digit 0.
3. There would be no two or more consecutive 0's in the digit sequence.
4. The digit sequence would be formed by only using digits from 0-9.

[The below code can encode only four digit number. I was trying to improve it for any random digit without violating the assumptions but at last i was out of moves

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n,r,a[4],i=0,j,k,l,m,h,t;
    printf("enter the 4 digit no \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n!=0)
    {
        r=n%10;
        a[i]=r;
        n=n/10;
        i++;
    }
    m=a[0];
    l=a[1];
    k=a[2];
    j=a[3];
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",j,k,l,m);
    if (j==0||((k==0&&l==0)||(l==0&&m==0)))
        printf("INVALID CODE");
    else{
        if (k>0&&m>0)
            printf("%c%c%c%c\n",64+j,64+k,64+l,64+m);
        t=(l*10)+m; 
        if (t<=26&&k>0)
            printf("%c%c%c\n",64+j,64+k,64+t);
        t=(k*10)+l; 
        if ((k>0&&t<=26)&&m>0)
            printf("%c%c%c\n",64+j,64+t,64+m);
        t=(j*10)+k; 
        if (t<=26&&m>0)
            printf("%c%c%c\n",64+t,64+l,64+m);
        h=(l*10)+m;
        if(t<=26 && h<=26)
            printf("%c%c\n",64+t,64+h);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to show it, together with a detailed explanation of the problems you have with it. I also suggest you spend some time with a debugger to step through your code.

Comment: I initially missed your code as it is a tiny link at the end. But please do not post images or links to images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Post it as formatted text in the question itself.

Comment: @kaylum word by word, line by line, they are all the same :))

Comment: @Hitokiri I thought so too at first.. But this question is better than the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201810/encoding-digits-to-alphabets) because at least here we have some (hard to see) code.

Comment: There should be an elegant solution with a recursive function. Post your code in text.

Comment: I've improved the formatting of your code somewhat but it's still not indented properly. Please fix up the indentation to make it readable.

Comment: The technical term you want to search for is "permutations".

Comment: If you encode the most used letters (ESANTIRUL?) to digits 1 to 9, your encoding efficiency increases.

Comment: Your post does not ask a question except in the title, for which the answer is yes. State the question you want to ask.

Comment: “Number of possible decodings for an empty sequence is 0” is incorrect. An empty sequence encodes one string; its decoding is the empty string.

Comment: @Lundin: How do you figure permutations are involved?

Comment: @pmg: What leads you to think OP is seeking a more efficient encoding? Or that their input population will be drawn from English text, given that their examples are not?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil:i didn't mention the encoding is done from digits to strings,it can be to character also

Comment: @Eric Postpischil:The above code can encode only four digit number. I was trying to improve it for any random digit without violating the assumptions this was the question

Comment: You probably want a backtracking search that checks whether the next two digits are a number between 1 and 26, proceeds on that basis if so, and then goes back and reinterprets them as individual digits. You might also store each chunk of the string as either a single interpretation or a pair of them.